# Web scrapping XML page but structure is incorrect using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO22l.png)I am trying to web-scrap Shazam, but having difficulty with the structure it returns.

My code is:

```python
url= shazam_page
requested= requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(requested.content, 'lmxl')
```

The information in the soup doesnt look right. I can not get any of the h1, class items in the page.

I am not too sure what the issue can be? Some content is in the soup, but its not anything like the website.

*https://www.shazam.com/charts/top-200/world*

Comment: please, no screenshots of text ... copy and add text itself

Comment: Did you mean `'lxml'` ?

Comment: He means add you whole code, which we can copy and reproduce easy.

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 1):

The data you see on the page is loaded via Ajax from different URL. To get the tracks data you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.shazam.com/shazam/v3/en-US/US/web/-/tracks/world-chart-world"
params = {"pageSize": 200, "startFrom": 0}
data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i, track in enumerate(data["tracks"], 1):
    print(
        "{:>03} {:<30} {:<30}".format(
            i, track["title"][:30], track["subtitle"][:30]
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
001 Yours                          JIN                           
002 As It Was                      Harry Styles                  
003 Running Up That Hill (A Deal W Kate Bush                     
004 1, 2, 3                        Sofia Reyes feat. Jason Derulo
005 Glimpse of Us                  Joji                          
006 Calm Down                      Rema                          
007 Bam Bam                        Camila Cabello Feat. Ed Sheera
008 The Logical Song               Supertramp                    
009 About Damn Time                Lizzo                         
010 Hold My Hand                   Lady Gaga                     
011 BREAK MY SOUL                  Beyoncé                       
012 Ferrari                        James Hype & Miggy Dela Rosa  

...and so on.
```

Comment: Sorry Andrej, I would like to pull many countries top 200 shazamed songs. I am not to sure what you did to generate that url? For countries, the URL is something like https://www.shazam.com/charts/top-200/united-kingdom